# ProviderError: max code size exceeded - Hardhat

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Iam trying to deploy a contract in ropsten testnet using hardhat but its throwing max code size exceeded error.

- i tried this [example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98340/providererror-max-code-%20%20%20%20size-exceeded/98345#98345.) bud didn't work
- added (allowUnlimitedContractSize: true) but didn't work.
- find the original contract  - [here](https://github.com/enzymefinance/protocol/blob/current/contracts/release/core/fund/comptroller/ComptrollerLib.sol)

contract code here:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;
contract ComptrollerLib is IComptroller, AssetFinalityResolver {
    using AddressArrayLib for address[];
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for ERC20;

    event MigratedSharesDuePaid(uint256 sharesDue);
    event OverridePauseSet(bool indexed overridePause);
    event PreRedeemSharesHookFailed(
        bytes failureReturnData,
        address redeemer,
        uint256 sharesQuantity
    );

    event SharesBought(
        address indexed caller,
        address indexed buyer,
        uint256 investmentAmount,
        uint256 sharesIssued,
        uint256 sharesReceived
    );

    event SharesRedeemed(
        address indexed redeemer,
        uint256 sharesQuantity,
        address[] receivedAssets,
        uint256[] receivedAssetQuantities
    );

    event VaultProxySet(address vaultProxy);

    uint256 private constant SHARES_UNIT = 10**18;
    address private immutable DISPATCHER;
    address private immutable FUND_DEPLOYER;
    address private immutable FEE_MANAGER;
    address private immutable INTEGRATION_MANAGER;
    address private immutable PRIMITIVE_PRICE_FEED;
    address private immutable POLICY_MANAGER;
    address private immutable VALUE_INTERPRETER;


    address internal denominationAsset;
    address internal vaultProxy;
    bool internal isLib;

   
    uint256 internal sharesActionTimelock;
    mapping(address => uint256) internal acctToLastSharesAction;

 
    modifier allowsPermissionedVaultAction {
        __assertPermissionedVaultActionNotAllowed();
        permissionedVaultActionAllowed = true;
        _;
        permissionedVaultActionAllowed = false;
    }

    modifier locksReentrance() {
        __assertNotReentranceLocked();
        reentranceLocked = true;
        _;
        reentranceLocked = false;
    }

    modifier onlyActive() {
        __assertIsActive(vaultProxy);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyNotPaused() {
        __assertNotPaused();
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyFundDeployer() {
        __assertIsFundDeployer(msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        __assertIsOwner(msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    modifier timelockedSharesAction(address _account) {
        __assertSharesActionNotTimelocked(_account);
        _;
        acctToLastSharesAction[_account] = block.timestamp;
    }

 

    function __assertIsActive(address _vaultProxy) private pure {
        require(_vaultProxy != address(0), "Fund not active");
    }

    function __assertIsFundDeployer(address _who) private view {
        require(_who == FUND_DEPLOYER, "Only FundDeployer callable");
    }

    function __assertIsOwner(address _who) private view {
        require(_who == IVault(vaultProxy).getOwner(), "Only fund owner callable");
    }

    function __assertLowLevelCall(bool _success, bytes memory _returnData) private pure {
        require(_success, string(_returnData));
    }

    function __assertNotPaused() private view {
        require(!__fundIsPaused(), "Fund is paused");
    }

    function __assertNotReentranceLocked() private view {
        require(!reentranceLocked, "Re-entrance");
    }

    function __assertPermissionedVaultActionNotAllowed() private view {
        require(!permissionedVaultActionAllowed, "Vault action re-entrance");
    }

    function __assertSharesActionNotTimelocked(address _account) private view {
        require(
            block.timestamp.sub(acctToLastSharesAction[_account]) >= sharesActionTimelock,
            "Shares action timelocked"
        );
    }

    constructor(
        address _dispatcher,
        address _fundDeployer,
        address _valueInterpreter,
        address _feeManager,
        address _integrationManager,
        address _policyManager,
        address _primitivePriceFeed,
        address _synthetixPriceFeed,
        address _synthetixAddressResolver
    ) public AssetFinalityResolver(_synthetixPriceFeed, _synthetixAddressResolver) {
        DISPATCHER = _dispatcher;
        FEE_MANAGER = _feeManager;
        FUND_DEPLOYER = _fundDeployer;
        INTEGRATION_MANAGER = _integrationManager;
        PRIMITIVE_PRICE_FEED = _primitivePriceFeed;
        POLICY_MANAGER = _policyManager;
        VALUE_INTERPRETER = _valueInterpreter;
        isLib = true;
    }

    function callOnExtension(
        address _extension,
        uint256 _actionId,
        bytes calldata _callArgs
    ) external override onlyNotPaused onlyActive locksReentrance allowsPermissionedVaultAction {
        require(
            _extension == FEE_MANAGER || _extension == INTEGRATION_MANAGER,
            "callOnExtension: _extension invalid"
        );

        IExtension(_extension).receiveCallFromComptroller(msg.sender, _actionId, _callArgs);
    }

    function setOverridePause(bool _nextOverridePause) external onlyOwner {
        require(_nextOverridePause != overridePause, "setOverridePause: Value already set");

        overridePause = _nextOverridePause;

        emit OverridePauseSet(_nextOverridePause);
    }

   
    function vaultCallOnContract(
        address _contract,
        bytes4 _selector,
        bytes calldata _encodedArgs
    ) external onlyNotPaused onlyActive onlyOwner {
        require(
            IFundDeployer(FUND_DEPLOYER).isRegisteredVaultCall(_contract, _selector),
            "vaultCallOnContract: Unregistered"
        );

        IVault(vaultProxy).callOnContract(_contract, abi.encodePacked(_selector, _encodedArgs));
    }

    
    function __fundIsPaused() private view returns (bool) {
        return
            IFundDeployer(FUND_DEPLOYER).getReleaseStatus() ==
            IFundDeployer.ReleaseStatus.Paused &&
            !overridePause;
    }

   
   
    function permissionedVaultAction(VaultAction _action, bytes calldata _actionData)
        external
        override
        onlyNotPaused
        onlyActive
    {
        __assertPermissionedVaultAction(msg.sender, _action);

        if (_action == VaultAction.AddTrackedAsset) {
            __vaultActionAddTrackedAsset(_actionData);
        } else if (_action == VaultAction.ApproveAssetSpender) {
            __vaultActionApproveAssetSpender(_actionData);
        } else if (_action == VaultAction.BurnShares) {
            __vaultActionBurnShares(_actionData);
        } else if (_action == VaultAction.MintShares) {
            __vaultActionMintShares(_actionData);
        } else if (_action == VaultAction.RemoveTrackedAsset) {
            __vaultActionRemoveTrackedAsset(_actionData);
        } else if (_action == VaultAction.TransferShares) {
            __vaultActionTransferShares(_actionData);
        } else if (_action == VaultAction.WithdrawAssetTo) {
            __vaultActionWithdrawAssetTo(_actionData);
        }
    }

    function __assertPermissionedVaultAction(address _caller, VaultAction _action) private view {
        require(
            permissionedVaultActionAllowed,
            "__assertPermissionedVaultAction: No action allowed"
        );

        if (_caller == INTEGRATION_MANAGER) {
            require(
                _action == VaultAction.ApproveAssetSpender ||
                    _action == VaultAction.AddTrackedAsset ||
                    _action == VaultAction.RemoveTrackedAsset ||
                    _action == VaultAction.WithdrawAssetTo,
                "__assertPermissionedVaultAction: Not valid for IntegrationManager"
            );
        } else if (_caller == FEE_MANAGER) {
            require(
                _action == VaultAction.BurnShares ||
                    _action == VaultAction.MintShares ||
                    _action == VaultAction.TransferShares,
                "__assertPermissionedVaultAction: Not valid for FeeManager"
            );
        } else {
            revert("__assertPermissionedVaultAction: Not a valid actor");
        }
    }

    function __vaultActionAddTrackedAsset(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        address asset = abi.decode(_actionData, (address));
        IVault(vaultProxy).addTrackedAsset(asset);
    }

    function __vaultActionApproveAssetSpender(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        (address asset, address target, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(
            _actionData,
            (address, address, uint256)
        );
        IVault(vaultProxy).approveAssetSpender(asset, target, amount);
    }

    function __vaultActionBurnShares(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        (address target, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(_actionData, (address, uint256));
        IVault(vaultProxy).burnShares(target, amount);
    }

    function __vaultActionMintShares(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        (address target, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(_actionData, (address, uint256));
        IVault(vaultProxy).mintShares(target, amount);
    }

    function __vaultActionRemoveTrackedAsset(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        address asset = abi.decode(_actionData, (address));

        if (asset != denominationAsset) {
            IVault(vaultProxy).removeTrackedAsset(asset);
        }
    }

    function __vaultActionTransferShares(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        (address from, address to, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(
            _actionData,
            (address, address, uint256)
        );
        IVault(vaultProxy).transferShares(from, to, amount);
    }

    function __vaultActionWithdrawAssetTo(bytes memory _actionData) private {
        (address asset, address target, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(
            _actionData,
            (address, address, uint256)
        );
        IVault(vaultProxy).withdrawAssetTo(asset, target, amount);
    }

  
    function init(address _denominationAsset, uint256 _sharesActionTimelock) external override {
        require(denominationAsset == address(0), "init: Already initialized");
        require(
            IPrimitivePriceFeed(PRIMITIVE_PRICE_FEED).isSupportedAsset(_denominationAsset),
            "init: Bad denomination asset"
        );

        denominationAsset = _denominationAsset;
        sharesActionTimelock = _sharesActionTimelock;
    }

   
    function configureExtensions(
        bytes calldata _feeManagerConfigData,
        bytes calldata _policyManagerConfigData
    ) external override onlyFundDeployer {
        if (_feeManagerConfigData.length > 0) {
            IExtension(FEE_MANAGER).setConfigForFund(_feeManagerConfigData);
        }
        if (_policyManagerConfigData.length > 0) {
            IExtension(POLICY_MANAGER).setConfigForFund(_policyManagerConfigData);
        }
    }

  
    function activate(address _vaultProxy, bool _isMigration) external override onlyFundDeployer {
        vaultProxy = _vaultProxy;

        emit VaultProxySet(_vaultProxy);

        if (_isMigration) {
            
            uint256 sharesDue = ERC20(_vaultProxy).balanceOf(_vaultProxy);
            if (sharesDue > 0) {
                IVault(_vaultProxy).transferShares(
                    _vaultProxy,
                    IVault(_vaultProxy).getOwner(),
                    sharesDue
                );

                emit MigratedSharesDuePaid(sharesDue);
            }
        }

        IVault(_vaultProxy).addTrackedAsset(denominationAsset);

        IExtension(FEE_MANAGER).activateForFund(_isMigration);
        IExtension(INTEGRATION_MANAGER).activateForFund(_isMigration);
        IExtension(POLICY_MANAGER).activateForFund(_isMigration);
    }

    function destruct()
        external
        override
        onlyFundDeployer
        onlyNotPaused
        allowsPermissionedVaultAction
    {
        require(!isLib, "destruct: Only delegate callable");

        IExtension(FEE_MANAGER).deactivateForFund();
        IExtension(INTEGRATION_MANAGER).deactivateForFund();
        IExtension(POLICY_MANAGER).deactivateForFund();

        selfdestruct(address(0));
    }

   
    function calcGav(bool _requireFinality) public override returns (uint256 gav_, bool isValid_) {
        address vaultProxyAddress = vaultProxy;
        address[] memory assets = IVault(vaultProxyAddress).getTrackedAssets();
        if (assets.length == 0) {
            return (0, true);
        }

        uint256[] memory balances = new uint256[](assets.length);
        for (uint256 i; i < assets.length; i++) {
            balances[i] = __finalizeIfSynthAndGetAssetBalance(
                vaultProxyAddress,
                assets[i],
                _requireFinality
            );
        }

        (gav_, isValid_) = IValueInterpreter(VALUE_INTERPRETER).calcCanonicalAssetsTotalValue(
            assets,
            balances,
            denominationAsset
        );

        return (gav_, isValid_);
    }

    function calcGrossShareValue(bool _requireFinality)
        external
        override
        returns (uint256 grossShareValue_, bool isValid_)
    {
        uint256 gav;
        (gav, isValid_) = calcGav(_requireFinality);

        grossShareValue_ = __calcGrossShareValue(
            gav,
            ERC20(vaultProxy).totalSupply(),
            10**uint256(ERC20(denominationAsset).decimals())
        );

        return (grossShareValue_, isValid_);
    }

    function __calcGrossShareValue(
        uint256 _gav,
        uint256 _sharesSupply,
        uint256 _denominationAssetUnit
    ) private pure returns (uint256 grossShareValue_) {
        if (_sharesSupply == 0) {
            return _denominationAssetUnit;
        }

        return _gav.mul(SHARES_UNIT).div(_sharesSupply);}

  
    function buyShares(
        address[] calldata _buyers,
        uint256[] calldata _investmentAmounts,
        uint256[] calldata _minSharesQuantities
    )
        external
        onlyNotPaused
        locksReentrance
        allowsPermissionedVaultAction
        returns (uint256[] memory sharesReceivedAmounts_)
    {
        require(_buyers.length > 0, "buyShares: Empty _buyers");
        require(
            _buyers.length == _investmentAmounts.length &&
                _buyers.length == _minSharesQuantities.length,
            "buyShares: Unequal arrays"
        );

        address vaultProxyCopy = vaultProxy;
        __assertIsActive(vaultProxyCopy);
        require(
            !IDispatcher(DISPATCHER).hasMigrationRequest(vaultProxyCopy),
            "buyShares: Pending migration"
        );

        (uint256 gav, bool gavIsValid) = calcGav(true);
        require(gavIsValid, "buyShares: Invalid GAV");

        __buySharesSetupHook(msg.sender, _investmentAmounts, gav);

        address denominationAssetCopy = denominationAsset;
        uint256 sharePrice = __calcGrossShareValue(
            gav,
            ERC20(vaultProxyCopy).totalSupply(),
            10**uint256(ERC20(denominationAssetCopy).decimals())
        );

        sharesReceivedAmounts_ = new uint256[](_buyers.length);
        for (uint256 i; i < _buyers.length; i++) {
            sharesReceivedAmounts_[i] = __buyShares(
                _buyers[i],
                _investmentAmounts[i],
                _minSharesQuantities[i],
                vaultProxyCopy,
                sharePrice,
                gav,
                denominationAssetCopy
            );

            gav = gav.add(_investmentAmounts[i]);
        }

        __buySharesCompletedHook(msg.sender, sharesReceivedAmounts_, gav);

        return sharesReceivedAmounts_;
    }

    function __buyShares(
        address _buyer,
        uint256 _investmentAmount,
        uint256 _minSharesQuantity,
        address _vaultProxy,
        uint256 _sharePrice,
        uint256 _preBuySharesGav,
        address _denominationAsset
    ) private timelockedSharesAction(_buyer) returns (uint256 sharesReceived_) {
        require(_investmentAmount > 0, "__buyShares: Empty _investmentAmount");

        
        __preBuySharesHook(_buyer, _investmentAmount, _minSharesQuantity, _preBuySharesGav);

        uint256 sharesIssued = _investmentAmount.mul(SHARES_UNIT).div(_sharePrice);

        uint256 prevBuyerShares = ERC20(_vaultProxy).balanceOf(_buyer);
        IVault(_vaultProxy).mintShares(_buyer, sharesIssued);

        
        ERC20(_denominationAsset).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _vaultProxy, _investmentAmount);

        __postBuySharesHook(_buyer, _investmentAmount, sharesIssued, _preBuySharesGav);

        
        sharesReceived_ = ERC20(_vaultProxy).balanceOf(_buyer).sub(prevBuyerShares);
        require(
            sharesReceived_ >= _minSharesQuantity,
            "__buyShares: Shares received < _minSharesQuantity"
        );

        emit SharesBought(msg.sender, _buyer, _investmentAmount, sharesIssued, sharesReceived_);

        return sharesReceived_;
    }

    function __buySharesCompletedHook(
        address _caller,
        uint256[] memory _sharesReceivedAmounts,
        uint256 _gav
    ) private {
        IPolicyManager(POLICY_MANAGER).validatePolicies(
            address(this),
            IPolicyManager.PolicyHook.BuySharesCompleted,
            abi.encode(_caller, _sharesReceivedAmounts, _gav)
        );

        IFeeManager(FEE_MANAGER).invokeHook(
            IFeeManager.FeeHook.BuySharesCompleted,
            abi.encode(_caller, _sharesReceivedAmounts),
            _gav
        );
    }

    function __buySharesSetupHook(
        address _caller,
        uint256[] memory _investmentAmounts,
        uint256 _gav
    ) private {
        IPolicyManager(POLICY_MANAGER).validatePolicies(
            address(this),
            IPolicyManager.PolicyHook.BuySharesSetup,
            abi.encode(_caller, _investmentAmounts, _gav)
        );

        IFeeManager(FEE_MANAGER).invokeHook(
            IFeeManager.FeeHook.BuySharesSetup,
            abi.encode(_caller, _investmentAmounts),
            _gav
        );
    }

   
    function __preBuySharesHook(
        address _buyer,
        uint256 _investmentAmount,
        uint256 _minSharesQuantity,
        uint256 _gav
    ) private {
        IFeeManager(FEE_MANAGER).invokeHook(
            IFeeManager.FeeHook.PreBuyShares,
            abi.encode(_buyer, _investmentAmount, _minSharesQuantity),
            _gav
        );

        IPolicyManager(POLICY_MANAGER).validatePolicies(
            address(this),
            IPolicyManager.PolicyHook.PreBuyShares,
            abi.encode(_buyer, _investmentAmount, _minSharesQuantity, _gav)
        );
    }

    function __postBuySharesHook(
        address _buyer,
        uint256 _investmentAmount,
        uint256 _sharesIssued,
        uint256 _preBuySharesGav
    ) private {
        uint256 gav = _preBuySharesGav.add(_investmentAmount);
        IFeeManager(FEE_MANAGER).invokeHook(
            IFeeManager.FeeHook.PostBuyShares,
            abi.encode(_buyer, _investmentAmount, _sharesIssued),
            gav
        );

        IPolicyManager(POLICY_MANAGER).validatePolicies(
            address(this),
            IPolicyManager.PolicyHook.PostBuyShares,
            abi.encode(_buyer, _investmentAmount, _sharesIssued, gav)
        );
    }

  
    
    function redeemShares()
        external
        returns (address[] memory payoutAssets_, uint256[] memory payoutAmounts_)
    {
        return
            __redeemShares(
                msg.sender,
                ERC20(vaultProxy).balanceOf(msg.sender),
                new address[](0),
                new address[](0)
            );
    }

    
           function redeemSharesDetailed(
        uint256 _sharesQuantity,
        address[] calldata _additionalAssets,
        address[] calldata _assetsToSkip
    ) external returns (address[] memory payoutAssets_, uint256[] memory payoutAmounts_) {
        return __redeemShares(msg.sender, _sharesQuantity, _additionalAssets, _assetsToSkip);
    }

   
  
    function __parseRedemptionPayoutAssets(
        address[] memory _trackedAssets,
        address[] memory _additionalAssets,
        address[] memory _assetsToSkip
    ) private pure returns (address[] memory payoutAssets_) {
        address[] memory trackedAssetsToPayout = _trackedAssets.removeItems(_assetsToSkip);
        if (_additionalAssets.length == 0) {
            return trackedAssetsToPayout;
        }

        bool[] memory indexesToAdd = new bool[](_additionalAssets.length);
        uint256 additionalItemsCount;
        for (uint256 i; i < _additionalAssets.length; i++) {
            if (!trackedAssetsToPayout.contains(_additionalAssets[i])) {
                indexesToAdd[i] = true;
                additionalItemsCount++;
            }
        }
        if (additionalItemsCount == 0) {
            return trackedAssetsToPayout;
        }

        payoutAssets_ = new address[](trackedAssetsToPayout.length.add(additionalItemsCount));
        for (uint256 i; i < trackedAssetsToPayout.length; i++) {
            payoutAssets_[i] = trackedAssetsToPayout[i];
        }
        uint256 payoutAssetsIndex = trackedAssetsToPayout.length;
        for (uint256 i; i < _additionalAssets.length; i++) {
            if (indexesToAdd[i]) {
                payoutAssets_[payoutAssetsIndex] = _additionalAssets[i];
                payoutAssetsIndex++;
            }
        }

        return payoutAssets_;
    }

    
    function __preRedeemSharesHook(address _redeemer, uint256 _sharesQuantity)
        private
        allowsPermissionedVaultAction
    {
        try
            IFeeManager(FEE_MANAGER).invokeHook(
                IFeeManager.FeeHook.PreRedeemShares,
                abi.encode(_redeemer, _sharesQuantity),
                0
            )
         {} catch (bytes memory reason) {
            emit PreRedeemSharesHookFailed(reason, _redeemer, _sharesQuantity);
        }
    }

    
   
    function __redeemShares(
        address _redeemer,
        uint256 _sharesQuantity,
        address[] memory _additionalAssets,
        address[] memory _assetsToSkip
    )
        private
        locksReentrance
        returns (address[] memory payoutAssets_, uint256[] memory payoutAmounts_)
    {
        require(_sharesQuantity > 0, "__redeemShares: _sharesQuantity must be >0");
        require(
            _additionalAssets.isUniqueSet(),
            "__redeemShares: _additionalAssets contains duplicates"
        );
        require(_assetsToSkip.isUniqueSet(), "__redeemShares: _assetsToSkip contains duplicates");

        IVault vaultProxyContract = IVault(vaultProxy);

        
        if (!IDispatcher(DISPATCHER).hasMigrationRequest(address(vaultProxyContract))) {
            __assertSharesActionNotTimelocked(_redeemer);
            acctToLastSharesAction[_redeemer] = block.timestamp;
        }

        if (!__fundIsPaused()) {
          
            __preRedeemSharesHook(_redeemer, _sharesQuantity);
        }

        ERC20 sharesContract = ERC20(address(vaultProxyContract));
        require(
            _sharesQuantity <= sharesContract.balanceOf(_redeemer),
            "__redeemShares: Insufficient shares"
        );

        
        payoutAssets_ = __parseRedemptionPayoutAssets(
            vaultProxyContract.getTrackedAssets(),
            _additionalAssets,
            _assetsToSkip
        );
        require(payoutAssets_.length > 0, "__redeemShares: No payout assets");

        
        uint256 sharesSupply = sharesContract.totalSupply();
        vaultProxyContract.burnShares(_redeemer, _sharesQuantity);

        payoutAmounts_ = new uint256[](payoutAssets_.length);
        address denominationAssetCopy = denominationAsset;
        for (uint256 i; i < payoutAssets_.length; i++) {
            uint256 assetBalance = __finalizeIfSynthAndGetAssetBalance(
                address(vaultProxyContract),
                payoutAssets_[i],
                true
            );

            if (_sharesQuantity == sharesSupply) {
                payoutAmounts_[i] = assetBalance;
                if (payoutAssets_[i] != denominationAssetCopy) {
                    vaultProxyContract.removeTrackedAsset(payoutAssets_[i]);
                }
            } else {
                payoutAmounts_[i] = assetBalance.mul(_sharesQuantity).div(sharesSupply);
            }

            if (payoutAmounts_[i] > 0) {
                vaultProxyContract.withdrawAssetTo(payoutAssets_[i], _redeemer, payoutAmounts_[i]);
            }
        }

        emit SharesRedeemed(_redeemer, _sharesQuantity, payoutAssets_, payoutAmounts_);

        return (payoutAssets_, payoutAmounts_);
    }

   
    function getDenominationAsset() external view override returns (address denominationAsset_) {
        return denominationAsset;
    }

   
    function getLibRoutes()
        external
        view
        returns (
            address dispatcher_,
            address feeManager_,
            address fundDeployer_,
            address integrationManager_,
            address policyManager_,
            address primitivePriceFeed_,
            address valueInterpreter_
        )
    {
        return (
            DISPATCHER,
            FEE_MANAGER,
            FUND_DEPLOYER,
            INTEGRATION_MANAGER,
            POLICY_MANAGER,
            PRIMITIVE_PRICE_FEED,
            VALUE_INTERPRETER
        );
    }

    
    function getOverridePause() external view returns (bool overridePause_) {
        return overridePause;
    }

   
    function getSharesActionTimelock() external view returns (uint256 sharesActionTimelock_) {
        return sharesActionTimelock;
    }

    function getVaultProxy() external view override returns (address vaultProxy_) {
        return vaultProxy;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone know the fix. Thanks in advance

Comment: The contract goes beyond the maximum bytecode size permitted in Ethereum, which is 24kb. Unfortunately you will have to trim its size down.

Comment: You can use [hardhat-contract-sizer](https://github.com/ItsNickBarry/hardhat-contract-sizer) to find out the byte size of your contract.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thanks for the info. the contract size is 28kb

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to refactor you code to make it smaller.

You could reduce the code size by using Struct and libraries that act as external storage and help reduce the overall size of the contract.

You can also encode your data to pass only one argument to the function, This will make your function smaller.

In other words, your contract is to big.

Comment: Thanks for the response. instead of making it smaller do we have any turn around ?, because i already have 40+ contracts and difficult to manage in refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable optimisation if you face such error at time of compilation,This will help you hope so! Try to select run as 200 and optimisation enabled

Comment: iam able to compile but not able to deploy.find confgig(settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 1000,
      details: {
        yul: false, // https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11638
      },
    },
  }, )i have used this config in hardhat.config.js. do i need to change anything here. thanks for the response