# UniswapV2Router02 exceeds size limit of 24kb so how to delploy UniswapV2Router02 to testnet?

Tags: contract-deployment

I'm trying to deploy UniswapV2Router02 to one of testnets
https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol

I continuously get ProviderError: max code size exceeded.
I tried to set hardhat optimization to true like here with 200 runs but it's still not working
[ProviderError: max code size exceeded](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98340/providererror-max-code-size-exceeded)

Comment: You have to use a higher number for the runs.

Comment: The contract size was changed meanwhile. I needed to remove some unused functions from Router and then it worked.